# Find the number of correct answers on each part of the exam

Tags: linear-algebra

A student took an exam with two parts, A and B, and he answered a total of 27 questions correctly. Each correct answer in part A was worth 5 points, while each correct answer in part B was worth 2 points. If the student’s total score on the exam was 84 points, how many questions did he answer correctly in part B?

---

**Progress so far**: the student got 84 points and 27 correctly, so every question is worth 84/27. But I don't know how to calculate specifically part a or b.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: well the student got 84 points and 27 correctly so every question worth 84/27 but I don't know how to calculate specifically part a or b the question didn't say

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a typo?

Comment: If the student got no answers from part B correct, he would have 27 correct answers in part A, and so he would have $5 \cdot 27 = 135$ points. He doesn't have 135 points, so that didn't happen. We have more information than it appears at first. Hint: let $x$ be the number of correct answers the student got from part A, and $y$ be the number he got correct from part B.

Comment: I won't give the solution but you can create two equations one related to the total number of questions answered correctly and one related to the total number of points. This is simply a system of linear equations, you could use linear algebra but with only two equations it would be a matter of substitutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Set up a system of equations and then solve for the two variables, this is similar to those "heads/legs" question.

Answer (score 0):

A + B = 27

5a + 2b = 84

Try to equalize the coefficients of the variables. By multiplying the entire opposite equation

5A + 5B = 135

5A + 2B = 84

A's are the same so they cancel out. You have two positives so you subtrack vertically now.

3B = 51

Divide by 3

B= 17

Plug B back into your first initial equation to get A

A+17 =27

A = 10

Now you have both